# Saving model to new Collection then destroying it using Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Wondering if someone can tell me if my approach is correct. I have 2 collections - Movies and Watchlist that both use the Movie Model. You can save a Movie into the Watchlist when the Model watchlist: true. I'm just not sure I'm doing this right however and would love for some feedback.

**JS**

```
onWatchlistAdd: function(model) {

        model.toggleWatchlist();

        this.dataStore.watchlist.add(model);

        model.save(null, {
            success: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log('Success::', model, response, options);
            },
            error: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log('Error::', model, response, options);
            }
        });
    },
onWatchlistRemove: function(model) {

        model.toggleWatchlist();

        this.dataStore.watchlist.remove(model);

        var clonedFilm = model.clone();

        clonedFilm.destroy(null, {
            success: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log('Success::', model, response, options);
            },
            error: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log('Error::', model, response, options);
            }
        });
    }
```

So my logic is, on adding to watchlist I set the models watchlist attribute to true then add it to watchlist then save the model. On remove I set the watchlist attribute to false, remove from the watchlist collection then clone and destroy so as not to completely remove the model. Does this seem right?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/styler/pen/obbdoe

Comment: model.destroy will remove it from the collection as well. I've no idea why you are creating a clone and then destroying the clone?!

Comment: If I use model.destroy then the model gets removed completely from the watchlist and the movie collection?

Comment: it'll be removed from the collection it is attached to. models has a collection property.

Comment: When I run model destroy in watchlist then go back to my movie collection the model is also removed from there though? That's why I'm cloning but that's also why I've asked the question in here as it doesn't feel right

Comment: You should share a [mcve] and explain what you're trying to achieve and what exactly is the problem. We don't know how you're creating the model and adding to these collections. We also don't know what goes on in `toggleWatchlist`.   Ideally you should be able to create a model in one collection, add the same in another and remove it from the later collection using it's `remove` method. Destroy will remove it from it's actual parent. You also seems to be doing `this.dataStore.watchlist.remove(model);` which could be the reason it gets removed from both collections.

Comment: Ok, I will update the code example soon (on mobile at moment). I have added a link to my codepen if that's of any use?

Comment: That codepen contains 500+ lines of code, which is not really useful. Trying to create a tiny demo is likely to help you solve the issue by yourself, if not, it'll be very helpful for the others to help you.

Comment: No problem T J thanks!

Comment: Hi @TJ, I moved my code out into a separate JSFiddle and you are right, my problem has disappeared. You can view the Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/wpyuym8b/2/ Could you possibly look over this and maybe suggest any improvements?